# SELECT User FROM mysql.user shows multiple instances of same user

Tags: mysql

Is this something I need to be concerned about?

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
+------------+
| User       |
+------------+
| icinga     |
| director   |
| icinga     |
| icingaweb2 |
| root       |
| root       |
| director   |
| icinga     |
| icingaweb2 |
| director   |
| icinga     |
| icingaweb2 |
| director   |
| icinga     |
| icingaweb2 |
| root       |
+------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mysql can have multiple entries for a user dependent on the source host of the connection, with the host part in the field `Host` of this table (try `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user`). This is perfectly normal and no reason to worry just by itself (but of course you have to check if the entries make sense for your environment).